# Redirect with POST parameters in MVC 4 for Payment Gateway Integration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, payment-gateway, http-status-code-400

I am trying to do a payment gateway integration using mvc4 in razor. In that i need to call a page with prefilled post form.

Using the below method, I am forming the post method form:

```
private static string PreparePOSTForm(string url, System.Collections.Hashtable data)      // post form
    {
        //Set a name for the form
        string formID = "PostForm";
        //Build the form using the specified data to be posted.
        StringBuilder strForm = new StringBuilder();
        strForm.Append("<form id=\"" + formID + "\" name=\"" +
                       formID + "\" action=\"" + url +
                       "\" method=\"POST\">");

        foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry key in data)
        {

            strForm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + key.Key +
                           "\" value=\"" + key.Value + "\">");
        }

        strForm.Append("</form>");
        //Build the JavaScript which will do the Posting operation.
        StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
        strScript.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
        strScript.Append("var v" + formID + " = document." +
                         formID + ";");
        strScript.Append("v" + formID + ".submit();");
        strScript.Append("</script>");
        //Return the form and the script concatenated.
        //(The order is important, Form then JavaScript)
        return strForm.ToString() + strScript.ToString();
    }
```

And in my Controller page I am calling the `PreparePostForm` with required parameter and I am receiving the POST request format.

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult OrderSummary()
        {
            string request=PreparePOSTForm("payment URL","hashdata required for payment")
            return Redirect(request);
        }
```

But while redirecting I am getting below error.

> Bad Request - Invalid URL
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

I am missing something here to work with POST request. Can someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot post a form by `Redirect` method. You could send generated form string to `View` and after that post the form by `Javascript`.

```
public ActionResult OrderSummary()
{
    string request=PreparePOSTForm("payment URL","hashdata required for payment")
    return View(model:request);
}
```

and in View of `OrderSummary`:

```
@model string

@Html.Raw(Model)

<script>
    $(function(){
       $('form').submit();
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create an `Action` with form which receives a `Model` in parameters. Then, just pass model when you redirect to this `Action`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OrderSummary()
{
    return RedirectToAction("OrderForm", new { HashData = hashData });
}

[HttpGet]
public ViewResult OrderForm(string hashData)
{
    OrderFormModel model = new OrderFormModel();
    model.HashData = hashData;
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OrderForm(OrderFormModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do processing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript.

Make a page which does have a html form and submit it through javascript and put your information as input:hidden in the form.

This will submit the data to the another place you want. Doing it in html gave you more control and you doesn't need to write a action like shown in other answer for every redirect in your app.